# i get the widget ID but im unable to generate a new one for each widget how can i achieve that?

Tags: android

i need to assign a new widget ID to each instance for the current widget i have so it wont update all the instances with the same data,when update service is triggered  how can i achieve that i have the following code :

```
@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    super.onEnabled(context);

     context = context.getApplicationContext();     
     ComponentName name = new ComponentName(context, FullWidgetProvider.class);
     ids = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).getAppWidgetIds(name);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With the [inflator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
inflater.inflate(resourceID, rootViewGroup);
```